# Why does a MixRGB node rotate my ColorRamp/mapping coordinates?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, mathematics, texture-coordinates

Why does a MixRGB node rotate my *ColorRamp*/mapping coordinates?

[image: without MixRGB: texture appears straight. With MixRGB: texture is skewed and squashed]

**The Fac is set to 0** so it should have no effect on anything at all. Also notice that the voronoi pattern is not rotated but the *ColorRamp*.

Comment: is there another way to mix two voronoi textures together? what else do i attach the coords to to rotate them?

Comment: You can mix the Voronoi textures together if you take their **color** outputs and plug them into the color1 and color2 sockets of the Mix node.

Comment: I'm not giving a full answer to this, as I don't comprehend the subject 100% and can't give you a detailed explanation, but: You are working with different data types. The position output is a vector with 2 channels (X and Y) in a range from -∞ to +∞.  The MIX RGB node expects color values ranging from 0 to 1 (without clamping practically to ∞). Blender converts your data so the data entering the mix rgb node is not the same data leaving it. you can check the difference by adding a "greater than" node set to 1 at the end (replacing your color ramp).

Comment: Can you add a picture of the full node tree?

Comment: Wow I'm surprised it worked at all then, I forgot that I was using position. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both your cases, (with and without your *Mix RGB* node) you are casting a 3-component vector to a 1-component scalar *Fac* input to the *Color Ramp* node. But Blender nodes do this differently for RGB Colors, and XYZ Vectors.

The cast from Color to scalar is done with an implicit *RGB to BW* node; i.e. it uses the [luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) of the color as its scalar result. The cast from Vector to scalar is done by taking the simple mean of the XYZ elements.

Since the *Position* output of your *Voronoi* node has a range of R and G values across the piece, varying exactly with X and Y in whatever texture-space you are using,  that explains the non-uniform interpretation of the colors as scalars across X and Y.

You could use a home-made 'Mix Vector' group, which would output a Vector, not a Color:

[image]

..but it would probably be better to find a way of achieving your desired effect without using the cast at all.